# How can I configure a hdfs (universally available storage) that can be accessed by all spark nodes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am new in Apache Spark. In my lab, I made a cluster with 8 pcs. I need to use some external universally available storage that can be accessed by all the nodes (hdfs is my choice). I have an unused ubuntu pc with static ip.

Can anybody please guide me how to

1. Install "Hadoop in Pseudo-Distributed Mode"
2. Upload data in installed hdfs server
3. Access this data from spark node (e.g. `RDD =sc.textFile("hdfs://bucketname/customer-orders.csv")`)

Comment: Did you take a look at the installation guidelines for hadoop and spark ?

Comment: Yah. But there are no such document or project available.